# how to use two type MakedInputFormatter for phonenumber in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to get two type Inputformatter, 000-000-0000 or 000-0000-0000 for phoneNumber.
I use flutter_multi_formatter. below code just allow put 000-000-0000.
I want inputformatter to make 000-000-0000 if the input length is 12.
I want inputformatter to maek 000-0000-0000 if the input length is 13.

```
Widget _phoneNumberFormField() {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextFormField(
        focusNode: _telephoneFocusNode,
        enabled: _verificationStatus == _VerificationStatus.none ? true : false,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        style: Theme.of(context)
            .textTheme
            .titleMedium!
            .copyWith(fontSize: 16.0.sp),
        controller: _phoneNumberEditingController,
        onChanged: (data) {
          _areAllTheFormsFilledAndValid();
        },
        validator: (phoneNumber) {
          if (phoneNumber!.length >= 12) {
            String pattern = r'(^01([0|1|6|7|8|9])-?([0-9]{3,4})-?([0-9]{4})$)';
            RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
            if (regExp.hasMatch(phoneNumber)) {
              return null;
            } else {
              return 'check phonenumber.';
            }
          }
          return null;
        },
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        inputFormatters: [
          MaskedInputFormatter("000-0000-0000"),
          MaskedInputFormatter("000-000-0000"),
        ],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            hintText: "put phonenumber.",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0.sp, color: Theme.of(context).hintColor),
            border: _outlineInputBorder()),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found way.

```
inputFormatters: [
          _phoneNumberEditingController.text.length == 12
              ? MaskedInputFormatter("000-0000-0000")
              : MaskedInputFormatter("000-000-00000")
        ],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).